# Adobe Flash CS3 sound in movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

There's an animation (MovieClip) in my scene. There's a sound accompanying animation. I inserted it into the first frame of the animation.
I want this animation to be inactive initially. I plan to activate it when some button is pressed.
I don't know how to set it "inactive" from within Adobe Flash workspace, so I just put in constructor of my scene:

MovieClip(getChildByName("MyAnim")).stop();

By it does not prevent that sound to start playing when my scene appears!

How do I manage it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, it usually isn't a good idea to insert sounds directly onto the timeline in flash. I strongly advice to import the .mp3 into the Flash program and play it by code using the AS3 **Sound class**.

EDIT: This way, the sound won't play until you use the Sound Class **.play()** method, which you could do at the beginning of your animation on the timeline OR from the button that activates it.

Here is a nice [Republic of Code tutorial](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sound/) giving you a step by step on how to play a Sound file using the AS3 Sound Class.

Comment: I agree, but that was not the question. Therefore, your answer is really more of a comment.

Comment: He was asking how to set a sound "inactive" and later "activate" it when a button is pressed, actions that are more than covered in the tutorial I linked, so I would say it is an answer after all... Anyways, I'll edit it so it is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Put the sound on frame two in your movieclip. Then go to that frame when you click the button.

```
private function onButtonClick(event : MouseEvent) : void
{
     mySoundClip.gotoAndStop(2);
}
```